# Good place to start learning data warehousing?

Tags: resources, data-warehouse

I am interested in learning more about data warehousing. I see terms like "dimension", "snowflake schema" and "star schema" thrown about. Where would one start in learning about this stuff? Are there good books or Internet resources?

ETL is in this space too right?

Comment: I don't understand how this is off-topic?

Answer (score 8):

Wikipedia's [resources on Data Warehousing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_warehouse) are good.

Reading any of [Ralph Kimball](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ralph_Kimball)'s books, such as "[The Data Warehouse Toolkit: The Complete Guide to Dimensional Modeling](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0471200247) "

Yes, [ETL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extract,_transform,_load) is in this space.

You may also be interested in [Column oriented databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS).

[Vertica](http://www.vertica.com/) have a blog with a few posts regarding how they're often better for what data warehouses are used for. For example "[Reflections on the Kimball Data Warehouse "Bible": Time for a New Testament?](http://databasecolumn.vertica.com/database-miscellaneous/reflections-on-the-kimball-data-warehouse-bible-time-for-a-new-testament/)" and "[The Truth About MPP & Data Warehousing](http://databasecolumn.vertica.com/database-architecture/the-truth-about-mpp-data-warehousing/)"

Comment: The link to "Reflections on the Kimball Data Warehouse "Bible":[...]" you give is broken. I believe this is the text:  http://databasecolumn.vertica.com/database-miscellaneous/reflections-on-the-kimball-data-warehouse-bible-time-for-a-new-testament/

Comment: Hi @Stephen & Jeff, I confused with the toolkit books of Kimball series, which is for what, like warehouse tool kit 2nd edition for complete ref. where as edition 3rd for definitive study, other are toolkit for lifecycle & ETL in warehousing. I would really appreciate if you focus on 2nd & 3rd edition of the warehousing toolkit & diff. Thanks.

Comment: The two links to the Vertica columns are dead :(

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, [Data Warehousing Tutorials](http://www.code2learn.com/search/label/Data%20Warehouse)